# Single Responsibility Principle Implementation on a specific code

Tags: java, solid-principles

How can this code be broken down to follow the principles of single responsibility principle? Even though I understand the SOLID principles and have read through many materials especially Uncle Bob's articles on SOLID principles I have unfortunately been unable to split the following code to two different classes to follow Single Responsibility Principle. I would highly appreciate help from StackOverflow

/** The only subclass the fully utilizes the
 Entity superclass (no other class requires
 movement in a tile based map).
 Contains all the gameplay associated with
 the Player.**/

```
package com.neet.DiamondHunter.Entity;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import com.neet.DiamondHunter.Manager.Content;
import com.neet.DiamondHunter.Manager.JukeBox;
import com.neet.DiamondHunter.TileMap.TileMap;
public class Player extends Entity {
    // sprites
    private BufferedImage[] downSprites;
    private BufferedImage[] leftSprites;
    private BufferedImage[] rightSprites;
    private BufferedImage[] upSprites;
    private BufferedImage[] downBoatSprites;
    private BufferedImage[] leftBoatSprites;
    private BufferedImage[] rightBoatSprites;
    private BufferedImage[] upBoatSprites;

    // animation
    private final int DOWN = 0;
    private final int LEFT = 1;
    private final int RIGHT = 2;
    private final int UP = 3;
    private final int DOWNBOAT = 4;
    private final int LEFTBOAT = 5;
    private final int RIGHTBOAT = 6;
    private final int UPBOAT = 7;

    // gameplay
    private int numDiamonds;
    private int totalDiamonds;
    private boolean hasBoat;
    private boolean hasAxe;
    private boolean onWater;
    private long ticks;

    // player status
    private int healthPoints;
    private boolean invincible;
    private boolean powerUp;
    private boolean speedUp;


    public Player(TileMap tm) {

        super(tm);

        width = 16;
        height = 16;
        cwidth = 12;
        cheight = 12;

        moveSpeed = 2;

        numDiamonds = 0;

        downSprites = Content.PLAYER[0];
        leftSprites = Content.PLAYER[1];
        rightSprites = Content.PLAYER[2];
        upSprites = Content.PLAYER[3];
        downBoatSprites = Content.PLAYER[4];
        leftBoatSprites = Content.PLAYER[5];
        rightBoatSprites = Content.PLAYER[6];
        upBoatSprites = Content.PLAYER[7];

        animation.setFrames(downSprites);
        animation.setDelay(10);

    }

    private void setAnimation(int i, BufferedImage[] bi, int d) {
        setAnimation(i, bi, d, false);
    }

    private void setAnimation(int i, BufferedImage[] bi, int d, boolean slowMotion) {
        currentAnimation = i;
        animation.setFrames(bi);
        animation.setDelay(d);
        slowMotion = true;
    }

    public void collectedDiamond() { numDiamonds++; }
    public int numDiamonds() { return numDiamonds; }
    public int getTotalDiamonds() { return totalDiamonds; }
    public void setTotalDiamonds(int i) { totalDiamonds = i; }

    public int getx() { return x; }
    public int gety() { return y; }
    public int getRow() { return rowTile; }
    public int getCol() { return colTile; }

    public void gotBoat() { hasBoat = true; tileMap.replace(22, 4); }
    public void gotAxe() { hasAxe = true; }
    public boolean hasBoat() { return hasBoat; }
    public boolean hasAxe() { return hasAxe; }

    public int getHealthPoints() { return healthPoints; }

    // Used to update time.
    public long getTicks() { return ticks; }

    // Keyboard input. Moves the player.
    public void setDown() {
        super.setDown();
    }
    public void setLeft() {
        super.setLeft();
    }
    public void setRight() {
        super.setRight();
    }
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
    }

    // Keyboard input.
    // If Player has axe, dead trees in front
    // of the Player will be chopped down.
    public void setAction() {
        final boolean pressUPKEY = currentAnimation == UP && tileMap.getIndex(rowTile - 1, colTile) == 21;
        final boolean pressDOWNKEY = currentAnimation == DOWN && tileMap.getIndex(rowTile + 1, colTile) == 21;
        final boolean pressLEFTKEY = currentAnimation == LEFT && tileMap.getIndex(rowTile, colTile - 1) == 21;
        final boolean pressRIGHTKEY = currentAnimation == RIGHT && tileMap.getIndex(rowTile, colTile + 1) == 21;
        if(hasAxe) {
            if(pressUPKEY) {
                tileMap.setTile(rowTile - 1, colTile, 1);
            }
            if(pressDOWNKEY) {
                tileMap.setTile(rowTile + 1, colTile, 1);
            }
            if(pressLEFTKEY) {
                tileMap.setTile(rowTile, colTile - 1, 1);
            }
            if(pressRIGHTKEY) {
                tileMap.setTile(rowTile, colTile + 1, 1);
            }
            JukeBox.play("tilechange");
        }
    }

    public void update() {

        ticks++;
        boolean current = onWater;
        onWater = CheckIfOnWater();

        //if going from land to water
        if(!current && onWater){
            JukeBox.play("splash");
        }

        // set animation
        setAnimationDown();
        setAnimationLeft();
        setAnimationRight();
        setAnimationUp();

        // update position
        super.update();

    }

    public void setAnimationUp() {
        if(up) {

            if(onWater && currentAnimation != UPBOAT) {
                setAnimation(UPBOAT, upBoatSprites, 10);
            }
            else if(!onWater && currentAnimation != UP) {
                setAnimation(UP, upSprites, 10);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setAnimationRight() {
        if(right) {

            if(onWater && currentAnimation != RIGHTBOAT) {
                setAnimation(RIGHTBOAT, rightBoatSprites, 10);
            }
            else if(!onWater && currentAnimation != RIGHT) {
                setAnimation(RIGHT, rightSprites, 10);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setAnimationLeft() {
        if(left) {


            if(onWater && currentAnimation != LEFTBOAT) {
                setAnimation(LEFTBOAT, leftBoatSprites, 10);
            }
            else if(!onWater && currentAnimation != LEFT) {
                setAnimation(LEFT, leftSprites, 10);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setAnimationDown() {
        if(down) {
            if(onWater && currentAnimation != DOWNBOAT) {
                setAnimation(DOWNBOAT, downBoatSprites, 10);
            }
            else if(!onWater && currentAnimation != DOWN) {
                setAnimation(DOWN, downSprites, 10);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckIfOnWater(){
        int index = tileMap.getIndex(ydest / tileSize, xdest / tileSize);
        if(index == 4) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    // Draw Player.
    public void draw(Graphics2D g)
    {
        super.draw(g);
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you have read many materials from Uncle Bob and you want to refactor this code, it means that you have a unit test suite covering this class, right ?

Comment: If your code is working, then http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a more appropriate venue for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement your components in a Model View Controller style, for example move all the code related to the update the view in a package yourapp.view for example, and move the code of your current class Player into a new class for example, GameBoard or GameView or whaterver, where the single responsability of this class is updating the model representations drawing the animations/images etc., in the gameboard screen. Another class for example, PlayerMovement and move all the code related to de keyboard events, currenly in your Player class, where the responsability of this class is catching the keys that makes the player move.

Move all the code related with game orders and desitions and move in another package yourapp.controller or actions or whatever, and create new classes for example PlayerController, GameController or whatever, where the single responsability of this class is receive the player requests to update the game models state, addressing commands and saying to the model classes be updated and saying to de view classes that gets the new model state every time that the model changes; for example when the player has a new location in the game board, or the location of some missil or some character die etc.

Put your model classes for example in other package for example yourapp.character or actors or whatever, and move the code related to the model state creating new classes that represent the game characters or actors or live elements that defining the behabior or roles of your game. For example the player or a Ship or a Cannon etc. This classes their responsability is only define the game character and their characteristis and behavior por example the location in the gameboard, their weapons, their powers, if is live or dead etc., and other info neded about their role into the game.

Try to identify and apply in a second stage, GoF pattern this can help you to refactor your code and make it more acurate to SOLID principles.

Answer (score 0):

Another of thinking about SRP is each unit should have a Single Reason for Change.

Take your class, what are the reasons one might change it in future:

- The sprites change.
- The animation changes.
- The gameplay changes.
- The player status logic changes.

Each of those you have organised fields for, so you spotted them yourself. Now just go one step further and create classes for each of those. So that you can change, for example, animation without touching code that affects gameplay. This:

- Makes changes safer (fewer side effects in the absence of a good test suite)
- Makes it easier to work on, you need to read less code, just the part you're interested in
- Makes it easier for your team to review changes (they will know you haven't affected gameplay while changing animation, for example)
- Makes it easier for a team to work on different parts of the system with less chance of merge conflicts
- Makes it easy to swap out one component for another implementation, you could, for example, re-skin your game by replacing the sprites component with another

Comment: Was this any help to you? Please upvote or accept helpful suggestions.